# HTTP header is not set to at least 15552000 seconds

Tags: 16.04, apache2, ssl, nextcloud

I am trying to clean up my installation of NextCloud 15 on Ubuntu 16.04. The overview page suggest this change:

> The "Strict-Transport-Security" HTTP header is not set to at least
>   "15552000" seconds. For enhanced security, it is recommended to enable
>   HSTS as described in the security tips ↗.

I went to the page that it suggests and it says to add the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName cloud.nextcloud.com
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>
 </VirtualHost>
```

So I believe I did but I'm still getting the same message.

Here is where I added it:

[image]

I restarted apache and I also restarted the server to see if it would take affect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you intend to use "add" instead of "set"? I have no idea if the rather opaque Apache or plugin conf rules matter in this regard.

Comment: @jdv thank you for the response. I tried both options in this case and neither made a difference.

Comment: Inspect the headers coming from this instance and see if _any_ of those are showing up. This might be a virtual host config issues. Now you are reminding me how much I hated ever touching Apache config, especially on shared or cloud hosting. If the headers are correct, then it might just be the reporting mechanism and you can ignore it?

Comment: I have the same problem, I run apache under Archlinux.

Comment: In my case it turned out that I put the set header directive for a wrong vhost...

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by entering:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

Maybe the `max-age` needs to be larger than 1552000, but I also executed the command:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

after inserting the line. As the response was something like:

> module headers has been enabled please restart Apache to take effect.

I assume that the module simply was not active before.
After restarting Apache and re-running the security verifier the message was gone.